# Why does __nss_database_lookup take most of the time in my numerical C++ program

Tags: c++, profiling

The line profiling output of `google-pprof` claims that most of the running time of my numerical C++ program is being spent in a function called `__nss_database_lookup` (see below).   Apparently that function is for handling things like the `passwd` file on UNIX systems. My C++ program should only be doing numerical calculations, allocating memory, and passing a few custom C++ data types around.

What's going on? Is the appearance of that function a mirage, a mere artefact of how `google-pprof` works?  Or is it actually being called and wasting two thirds of my program's running time?  If it is being called, what could be calling it? Has something mistakenly called it in one of my C++ classes? How would I track that down?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, `g++-7` and `g++-9`.

```
Total: 1046 samples
     665  63.6%  63.6%      665  63.6% __nss_database_lookup ??:0
     107  10.2%  73.8%      193  18.5% <function1> file.h:1035
      92   8.8%  82.6%       92   8.8% <function2> file.h:...
      87   8.3%  90.9%       87   8.3% <function3> file.h:995
      17   1.6%  92.5%      734  70.2% <function4> file.h:1128
...
```

(Function and file names obscured for confidentiality reasons)

Comment: This kind of report does not say anything about what part of code calls `__nss_database_lookup`. To get whole picture, you can build [CPU Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html) using perf.

Comment: While you're futzing around with pprof, just [*do this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) and find out what's *really* going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A friend of mine met the similar issue today. Though it has been a while after you raised the question, but I still would like to answer it so that anyone else who reaches here can get some hints.

This is because some local symbols (which corresponds to static local functions in C/C++) are called, and these symbols don't have their entries in the symbol table, and their text (code) is placed after `__nss_database_lookup`. So your perf tool treats them as a part of `__nss_database_lookup`.

For example, your program may call `memcpy`, and `memcpy` calls `__memmove_unaligned_avx_erms`, which is a local symbol in glibc and isn't exported in dynamic symbol table, and its code is placed after `__nss_database_lookup` coincidentally together with other local symbols. And your perf tool can find nothing about `__memmove_unaligned_avx_erms`, so it just thinks `__nss_database_lookup` is called.

A potential solution is to install libc-dbg package (the package name may vary on various distros), and if your perf tool is smart enough to automatically load the debug info, it may annotate symbols correctly. (My friend checked that it took some effects on `perf` tool)

Comment: It seems that gperftools/pprof is not smart enough to load the libc-dbg symbols :-/